# quiero hacer un login, con firebase, pero, al agregar los componentes de firebase, se rompe la pag

Tags: angular, firebase, login

este es mi app.module

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
    import { SharedModule } from './components/shared/shared.module';
    import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

    @NgModule({
       declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent],
     imports: [
     BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    SharedModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

    // ... the rest

    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
     export class AppModule {}
```

mi app routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '',
  component: LoginComponent,
  },
{
path: 'dashboard',
loadChildren: () =>
  import('./components/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
    (x) => x.DashboardModule
  ),
   },
 ];
 @NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [],
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

y por ultimo el loginComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private router: Router,
    private Auth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      User: ['', Validators.required],
      Password: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ingresar() {
    const user = this.form.value.User;
    const password = this.form.value.Password;

    if (user == 'junjse' && password == '1234') {
      this.fakeLoading();
    } else {
      this.error();
      this.form.reset();
    }
    /*this.Auth.(user,password).then((user)=>{
    console.log(user)
      this.fakeLoading();
  }).cathc((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
      this.form.reset();
      this.error();
  });*/
  }

  fakeLoading() {
    this.loading = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }, 1500);
  }

  error() {
    this.snackBar.open('usuario o contraseña son invalidos', '', {
      duration: 5000,
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      verticalPosition: 'top',
    });
  }
}
```

al realizar los cambio que se necesita, para habilitar firebase se rompe, por eso, el codigo de firebase esta comentado, intentando recuperar el estado anterior de la pag, que andaba.lo primero que se rompe es el router-outlet, el cual esta configurado, bien, va en el anterior estado, antes de firebase, funcionaba de 10.

ERROR
src/app/app.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2

```
src/app/app.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs i
```