# quiero realizar una pag, con enrutamiento, pero, no aparece los diferentes componentes

Tags: angular

este es mi app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { GaleryComponent } from './galery/galery.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'galery',
    component: GaleryComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, GaleryComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

despues oslo estan los componentes que estan ahi asignados.estoy empezando en angular y todavia me equivoco un poco, gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Comment: Las rutas se hacen en el AppRoutingModule, checa primero la documentación, se explica muy bien ahí cómo hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [quiero hacer un login, con firebase, pero, al agregar los componentes de firebase, se rompe la pag](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/598589/quiero-hacer-un-login-con-firebase-pero-al-agregar-los-componentes-de-firebas)

Answer (score 0):

Ese código está bien pero los componentes se renederizan en el router-outlet.
En tu app.component.html, borra todo y pon solo:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

En esa etiqueta se renderizaran los componentes asignados a cada url

Si te estás iniciando, te recomendaría que separaras el archivo de las rutas, Angular crea un archivo separado al inicializar el proyecto cuando te pregunta si quieres usar el router.

También te recomiendo que busques como hacer el enrutado con lazy load. Sirve para cargar los componentes a demanda, según donde los necesites, en vez de cargarlos al inicio de la aplicación.

Espero que te haya servido, un saludo.